# How to use alphanum.py?

Tags: python, sorting, alphanumeric

The [Alphanum algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html) ([python implementation](http://www.davekoelle.com/files/alphanum.py)) "sorts strings containing a mix of letters and numbers. Given strings of mixed characters and numbers, it sorts the numbers in value order, while sorting the non-numbers in ASCII order. The end result is a natural sorting order."

My attempt in python2.7 is below.

```
>>> import alphanum
>>> unsorted = ['NASEC-100', 'NASEC-200', 'NASEC-99', 'NASEC-101']
>>> sorted = unsorted[:]
>>> sorted.sort(alphanum)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: This is a custom module, so as long as it has been put in where python can see it it can be imported.  As the error indicates you are passing the module to sort(). You need to reference the function in the module so the call should be: `sorted.sort(alphanum.aplhanum)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the author of the script, Chris Hulan for the tip.  Here's the same scenario with it working:

```
>>> import alphanum
>>> unsorted = ['NASEC-100', 'NASEC-200', 'NASEC-99', 'NASEC-101']
>>> sorted = unsorted[:]
>>> sorted.sort(alphanum.alphanum)
>>> sorted
['NASEC-99', 'NASEC-100', 'NASEC-101', 'NASEC-200']
```

Answer (score 1):

I am just a beginner, but I don't remember a alphanum in the standard library of python.

If alphanum.py is something you wrote or downloaded try `from alphanum.py import *`.
I seem to remember having a similar issue with a module I built that was corrected using that instead of just import.

Comment: This is very useful and helpful.  The following works with your tip.
Thanks to the author of the script, Chris Hulan for the tip.  Here's the same scenario with it working:  
  
    >>> from alphanum import *  
    >>> unsorted = ['NASEC-100', 'NASEC-200', 'NASEC-99', 'NASEC-101']  
    >>> sorted = unsorted[:]  
    >>> sorted.sort(alphanum)  
    >>> sorted  
`    ['NASEC-99', 'NASEC-100', 'NASEC-101', 'NASEC-200']